# Заливка области

Tags: java

У меня есть фигура нарисованная через GeneralPath path;

Как мне ее закрасить цветом?

Через fill(path) не выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сделать фигуру, закрашенную красным цветом, нужно выполнить следующие команды:

```java
GeneralPath filledPolygon = ...;
filledPolygon.moveTo(...);
filledPolygon.closePath();

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setPaint(Color.red);
g2.fill(filledPolygon);
g2.draw(filledPolygon);
```